# How can I align the image to the right?

Tags: html, css, image

I want my image to float to the right. But if I use the float: right; write a command, it also takes the section with it. See image. The picture is already so far to the right because it is so big. (the rest is transparent).

[image: Image before and after float]

```css
#second {
  background-color: black;
}

.orange {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #F54703;
}

#secondBild {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section id="first">
    <img src="bilder/Oben_rechtsunten.png">
  </section>
  <section class="orange"></section>
  </section>
  <section id="second">
    <img src="bilder/Seite_unten.png" id="secondBild">
  </section>
  <section class="orange">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuimg when you state 'it takes the section with it' means that you want the section with id = 'second' to occupy the space and image within it to be pushed to the right. To do this you can set the wrapping div to display: flex then use flex-grow to cause the second section to expand. To move the image to the right within section 'second' you use margin-inline: auto 0;  You also have to make the image a block element too. If that's not what you're looking for drop me a comment and I'll edit.

Fully marked up html & css below

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

#second {
  flex-grow: 1; /* added this */
  background-color: black;
}

.orange {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #F54703;
}

#secondBild {
  /*float: right;*/
  margin-inline: auto 0; /* added this */
  display: block; /* added this */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section id="first">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200">
  </section>
  <section class="orange"></section>
  </section>
  <section id="second">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="secondBild">
  </section>
  <section class="orange">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found a way. I just put the image in the background, like this:

```
#first{
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url(bilder/Oben_rechtsunten.png);
    background-position: right;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float` property removes the element from the normal flow of the page,
so the block parent won't wrap the floating content. You can solve this by adding `display: flow-root` to the parent element to wrap its floating contents. Refer to [Block formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) for detailed information.

```
#second {
    display: flow-root;
}

#secondBild {
    float: right;
}
```

Another easy solution if you don't want to use `float` is adding `text-align: right;`
to the parent element.

```
#second {
    text-align: right; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
#img-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: right;
}

Use `display: flex;` and `align-items: right;`
```

```html
<div id="img-container">
  <img src="#" id="image">
</div>
```